# How to config multi file keycloak.json in Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I want to add multi file keycloak.json in my Spring boot (1.3.8) project. ex: 
`keycloak-dev.json and keycloak-live.json`

My project using Spring boot 1.3.8 and Keycloak: 2.2.1

Comment: Please post a reproducible example (your current code that the readers can execute) and a clear explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: not sure with keycalok 2.2.1 , with keycloak 5.0 you can do some thing like this https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/examples/multi-tenant/src/main/java/org/keycloak/example/multitenant/control/PathBasedKeycloakConfigResolver.java

Answer (score 0):

I already found way for this problem by add

```
keycloak.configurationFile=classpath:keycloak-dev.json
```

in `application-dev.properties`